# Laravel Blade Foreach only shows 10 items

Tags: php, database, laravel, laravel-blade

This loads 12 Candidates from the database.

```php
$candidates = Candidate::all()->where('vacancy_id', $id);
```

doing `count($candidates)` returns `12`

however in my foreach loop. such as

```php
$sum = 0;
@foreach($candidates as $candidate)
   $sum +=1;
@endforeach
```

yet `$sum` returns `10` instead of `12`.

any ideas?

Laravel 8
PHP 8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the reason you're trying to print 10 instead of 12 is so you can paginate, you should use Laravel's paginator:

`$candidates = Candidate::all()->where('vacancy_id', $id)->paginate(10);`

Comment: Hi John, I want to load all records, without pagination , any ideas on how to render everything?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
@foreach($candidates as $key => $candidate)
    @if($key < 10)  
        {{$candidate->value}}
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: tried this, still only get 10 values, i want all values to be printed.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your loop, if you use `all()` no need to use the `where` condition, with where condition use `get()`

```
$candidates = Candidate::where('vacancy_id', $id)->get();
```

**Your Loop**

```
@foreach($candidates AS $candidate_key => $candidate_value)
    @if($candidate_key <= 9)
        {{ $candidate_value->vacancy_id }}
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Answer (score -2):

why not just do it?

```
@foreach($candidates as $team)
    {{$loop->iteration}}
@endforeach
```

$loop->iteration: The current loop iteration (starts at 1).

more information here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade.

Answer (score -3):

try this one

$candidates = Candidate::where('vacancy_id', $id)->get();